# How to use Okhttpclient Create a Http Delete Or Put Method With Params? android okhttpclient

Tags: android, post, put, okhttp

Does anyone know in Android How to use Okhttpclient Create a Http Delete Or Put Method With Params?

Using java , this is what i have tried:

```
CookieJarImpl cookieJar = new CookieJarImpl(new PersistentCookieStore(context));

okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                .addInterceptor(new LoggerInterceptor("TAG"))
                .connectTimeout(10000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(10000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //其他配置     
                .build();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can build a URL with query parameters using the `HttpUrl` class. Then you can use an `okhttp3.Request.Buidler()` along with either the `post()` or `delete()` methods:

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .host(host).addQueryParameter(name, value).build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url).post(RequestBody.create(mediaType, body)).addHeader(type, header).build();

okhttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    ...
});
```

You can check out the [OkHttp wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki) for [recipes](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) if you need further help. Or you could use Square's other wonderful library, [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), which pairs well with OkHttp.